# Sitefinity CMS image fields turning by themselves empty

Tags: sitefinity

We have a Sitefinity 8.0 website running off an SQL Express 2014 database. Majority of the website is made up of modules built via the Module Builder.

Recently we have noticed image fields in the Module Builder modules are appearing empty and the version history is showing that no changes have been made.

I'm a bit short on ideas about why this might be happening.

Comment: So you edit an item that should have an image, but the field is empty? Do you see any javascript errors in the console?

Is it possible that the image itself is deleted from the library?

What happens if you add a new image, save and then Edit the item again - do you see the image?

Comment: So you edit an item that should have an image, but the field is empty? No, the item has had image set several months ago, has not been edited/updated and yet the image field is now empty.

Do you see any javascript errors in the console? No

Is it possible that the image itself is deleted from the library? The image is still present in the library.

What happens if you add a new image, save and then Edit the item again - do you see the image? Yes.

Comment: Hard to guess what might have happened in this case.

One possible cause - someone deleted the image field (and all its data) from the module and then re-added it again.